# NSDate after NSDateFormatter is null

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Why is the dateformatter returning null? objSelectedNote.notedate is of type NSDate. [NSDate date] works fine...

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSLog(@"%@", [df stringFromDate:obj_SelectedNote.notedate]);
NSLog(@"%@", obj_SelectedNote.notedate);
NSLog(@"%@", [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
[df release];
```

nslog responses:

```
2011-06-04 10:31:25.441 ail[40632:207] (null) 
2011-06-04 10:31:27.828 ail[40632:207] 2011-06-04 00:18:23 -0700
2011-06-04 10:31:30.340 ail[40632:207] 2011-06-04
```

Comment: The code you posted *should* work. I would suspect that something is wrong with `obj_SelectedNote.notedate`. Can you verify that it is in fact a valid `NSDate` object? `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClassName([obj_SelectedNote.notedate class]));`

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClassName([obj_SelectedNote.notedate class])); throwing compile error...

Comment: Sorry: It should be `NSStringFromClass(...)`

Comment: w/o any knowledge of obj_SelectedNote, I'd try casting it to an NSDate (eg. [df stringFromDate:((NSDate *)obj_SelectedNote.notedate)];

Comment: so the obj_SelectedNote.notedate is of type NSCFString. may be this is the problem. I am fetching this value from sqlite like this: const char *temp_notedate = (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectionStmt, 3); objNotes.notedate =  [NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_notedate];

Comment: I would say that's a good guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out there was a problem in retrieving the data from sqlite. This piece code help me solve it.

```
const char *temp_notedate = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectionStmt, 3);
            if(temp_notedate){
                NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                NSString *newstr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_notedate];
                [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
                NSDate * newdate = [df dateFromString:newstr];
                objNotes.notedate =  newdate; 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have only one user with this problem. And he fixed it switching from 12-h format to 24-h in his Settings. And I still can't reproduce it myself. And I do have proof of this!